How to get journalctl to use more disk space? It doesn't get close to SystemMaxUse
So I want to keep more log history that what journalctl allows, and I can't get it to use more than 5.7 GB, even though I configured SystemMaxUse to 20GB.
grep -v '^#' /etc/systemd/journald.conf
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
SystemMaxUse=20G

I don't see any other journalctl config files on the system.
I think there is enough space on the system so that should not be an issue.
df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs               3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  3.8G  252K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  3.8G  1.4M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   70G   30G   41G  43% /
/dev/sda2             1014M  552M  463M  55% /boot
/dev/sda1              599M  5.8M  594M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/rhel-home  121G   11G  110G   9% /home
tmpfs                  777M   44K  777M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                  777M  2.3M  775M   1% /run/user/258821895

